# Get listing of web services referenced in WCF application?

Tags: wcf, service, reference

Could anyone out there give some pointers on how to go about getting a listing of all the web service references used by a WCF application - the pseudo code I'm envisioning might look something like:

For each ws in MyWebServices
    Console.WriteLine("Service Name: " & ws.Name)
Next

How to build the MyWebServices object is what I am wondering?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
ClientSection clientSection = (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");

foreach(ChannelEndpointElement channelEndpointElement in clientSection.Endpoints)
{
    // Use any of the channel endpoint element properties here:
    // Address, BehaviorConfiguration, Binding, BindingConfiguration, Contract, etc.
}
```

Comment: Kind of a forehead slapper once I saw the answer.  Seems so obvious now.  Thanks for the help!

Both this answer and the answer below are correct but marking this one as 'answer' for completeness

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the configuration file. All WCF services used by the application should be in the client section.